# XPath выбрать узел без внутренних элементов

Tags: xml, xpath

Есть xml вида

```
<Rt xmlns:ns2="..." xmlns:ns3="..." >
    <a>first</a>
    <b>second</b>
....
</Rt>
```

Как с помощью XPath выбрать только корневой тег со всеми xmlns и атрибутами без внутренних тегов?

Т.е. получить только

```
<Rt xmlns:ns2="..." xmlns:ns3="..." >    
</Rt>
```

Пробую следующее выражение `//tns:Rt` и `/tns:Rt` все равно выбирает полностью со вложенными узлами. tns - одно из namespace по умолчанию

Comment: Считайте, что XPath возвращает ссылку на узел. Сам узел по-прежнему находится в DOM-дереве, со всеми своими дочерними узлами, атрибутами, неймспейсами. Если они не нужны - удалите их. Если документ xml портить нельзя, создайте новый самостоятельный узел, скопировав в него всё нужное из найденного узла.